# Odd Culture behaviour on ASP.Net forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, culture

Based on this code (taken/modified from the Microsoft site)...

```
int i = 100;
string op = "";

// Creates/Displays a CultureInfo for English in Belize.
CultureInfo bz = new CultureInfo("en-BZ");
op += (i.ToString("c", bz)) + "<br/>";

// Creates/Displays CultureInfo for English in GB.
CultureInfo gb = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
op += (i.ToString("c", gb)) + "<br/>";

// Creates/Displays a CultureInfo for English in the U.S.
CultureInfo us = new CultureInfo("en-US");
op += (i.ToString("c", us)) + "<br/>";

// Creates/Displays a CultureInfo for Danish in Denmark.
CultureInfo dk = new CultureInfo("da-DK");
op += (i.ToString("c", dk)) + "<br/>";

litOutput.Text = op;
```

please can anyone explain why this is the output I am getting..  (note the 3rd one, supposedly en-US)

```
BZ$100.00
£100.00
100,00 €
kr. 100,00
```

..and what I need to do to fix it.  It's only been a problem recently after I think somebody had a "play" on the server.

**Update/additional info**

If I run the same code in a stand-alone app on the server I get the expected results for the US culture, it's only when the code is running within ASPNet that things go weird.

TIA.

Comment: If you've got people messing with your server's culture stuff, I'd probably just give up and start over with a new server or new image. Who knows what else they messed up...

Comment: Unfortunately we're a bit "locked in" - not our choice of hosts

Comment: I do not get your same results, but my default culture is en-US.  What is the culture setting on the server?

Comment: My guess is the currency display settings on the server were customized rather than just changing the default culture.

Comment: I've updated my post. If I run the code as a console app I get the correct response (ie $100.00)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of searching, reading MS page after MS page I finally found the answer in the registry. As first thought somebody had been tinkering.

The default settings under `HKEY_USERS/.DEFAULT/Control Panel/International` had been changed so that the Country code/name/id all pointed at the US but the formats were European.

Swapping these to the correct values (either by swapping the country to the correct one, or changing the formats to US style) fixed the problem.

Thanks for your help. Hope this answer helps others.